# Is there a host node for ETC similar to infura?

Tags: web3js, ethereum-classic, ethernodes

I want to connect to a node test using web3's HTTPProvider, and I don't want to spend time deploying a node.

Comment: get it !!! ----> https://api.gastracker.io/web3

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, these are pretty difficult to find.

Here's another one: `https://etc-geth.0xinfra.com/`